# Save to Azure Storage works for Images, but not PDF

Tags: c#, azure, storage, azure-blob-storage

I've seen a few similar questions on here as I've spent the past 2 hours googling, and all their accepted answers seem to be the same - that the posted code is missing the
`contenttype = "application/pdf"`  line.

But as you can see, I have that line (was softcoded, now hardcoded to make sure), but still have the problem.

The problem is that I can upload jpg and png files to Azure storage, and it works fine. However pdf files upload perfectly, without error, but when I click on them in Azure Storage Explorer (inluding clicking Download) then a new tab opens up, but is blank.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
       public async Task<string> BlobStorageUploadFromFile(string filename)
    {
        string storageConnection = "[Connection String is Here]";
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnection);

        //Create a blob client
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        //Create a container 
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("attachments");

        //Create Adhoc security policy - (Create permissions with 1hr expiry)
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy adHocPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create
        };

        // Generate the shared access signature for the container, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
        string sasContainerToken = cloudBlobContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(adHocPolicy, null);

        //Fetch the container again using the containerURI with the secure token on the end
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer2 = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(cloudBlobContainer.Uri + sasContainerToken));

        //Get Blob reference
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer2.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
        cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf"; // GetMimeTypeFromURL(filename);

        using var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8);

        //Upload to Azure
        await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(sr.BaseStream);

        //This returns the URI but cannot open if PDF
        return cloudBlockBlob.Uri.ToString();

    }
```

cannot open the pdfs[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP88e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set correct permissions on the file. Check out the following:

```
         CloudBlobClient blobClient=cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
        var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("Your Tenant Id");
        await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        blobContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off });<== is this rightly set?
        var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"Your container/yourfile.pdf");   
        //upload as byte[]       
        await blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(your_file_bytes, 0, your_file_bytes.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks @Umar ... but I added that line and it made no difference  :-( 
I do have a SharedAccessBlobPermissions line in there, and the same code works ok for image files.

Answer (score 0):

Solved ... with a typical "microsoft solution" ...

Even though the image in the question was a snapshot of looking at the Storage Explorer in a Microsoft Edge browser ... that's not enough.

I downloaded the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer app for Windows, and low and behold ... I can download the same .pdf files which I uploaded, and can view them successfully ....

For other poor bastards suffering from Microsoftitis, please see the image and download that. Worked for me!

‍♂️

[image]